# Saving rows that belong to more than one table in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-3.0, saving-data

I am attempting to save an `Order` in a system with complex associations.

**Associations**

```
Transactions hasMany TransactionDetails
Transactions belongsTo Order

TransactionDetails belongsTo Transactions
TransactionDetails belongsTo OrderProducts

Orders hasMany Transactions
Orders hasMany OrderProducts

OrderProducts belongsTo Orders
OrderProducts hasMany TransactionDetails
```

**Attempt at a Save / The Problem**

However, when I save, it only saves the associated `id` from `OrderProducts`, and not from `Transactions`.

Building out the associated array for the `Orders` save here:

```
 $associated = [
        'Transactions',
        'OrderProducts' => ['associated' => 'TransactionDetails'],
        'OrderPackages' => ['associated' => [
             'OrderProducts' => ['associated' => 'TransactionDetails']
        ]
    ];
```

**Reason for these associations**

It is setup this way because in some areas we need to pull the `'Transactions' =>  'TransactionDetails'` together, and in others we will need to pull the `'OrderProducts' => 'TransactionDetails'` that are specific to that individual product.

**Question**

Is there a way to save an Order that will have a Transaction, and an OrderProduct that will have TransactionDetails which ALSO need to belong to the Transaction.  All of these are new saves (none of the rows exist before this save).

```
Order
    Transaction
    OrderProduct
        TransactionDetail
            order_product_id // <- needing this is assumed
            transaction_id // <- but also needs this
```